# WYSIWYG HTML Editor -> PDF (Prawn + Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

Is there a way to use the Prawn gem in Rails to create PDFs from the text in a WYSIWYG HTML Editor?

Need non-tech staff to be able to open up a WYSIWYG HTML Editor, edit the pdf text from a PDF generated by Prawn and then create a new PDF.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty difficult. The HTML editor will store the text internally as marked up HTML, and Prawn is defined using a Ruby DSL.

The best option would be not use marked up text, or use something easy to parse like markdown and then build a translator for Prawn.

Comment: Bit too high tech to build a translator. Guess I have to use the wicked-pdf gem instead. But now I know at least. Thank you.